# Yacc refers to meaningful rules as useless

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc

My `yacc` file is producing unexpected warnings:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define YYSTYPE char*
#define YYSTYPE int
#define YYSTYPE char
extern char *yytext;

%}

%token INT STR FLOAT INTEGER CHARACTER STRING IDENTIFIER UNARYOPR OPR
%token NOT LEFT_BKT RIGHT_BKT RELATIONOPR ASSIGNMENT IF ELIF
%token ELSE UNTIL WHILE ENDWHILE FOR RAW_INPUT INPUT PRINT
%token TERMINATOR DO SET SETATTRIBUTE FUNCDEC CLASSDEC IMPORT
%token FROM TYPE RETURN BREAK AND OR SQBR_L SQBR_R CUR_L CUR_R IN

%%
stmt
    : IMPORT STRING stmt {printf("Parsed import.\n");}
    | number
    | def {printf("def");}
    | initialization stmt {printf("init");}
    | statement {printf("somestmt");}

def
    : FUNCDEC STRING LEFT_BKT RIGHT_BKT stmt {printf("Defined function.");}

statement
    : initialization statement {printf("Statement"); }
    | print statement {printf("Statement"); }
    | inp statement
    | loop
    | condition
    ;

int
    : literal "=" number {printf("Integer");}

assign
    : literal "=" literal {printf("Assign");}

condition
    : if
    | else
    | elif
    ;

loop
    : forloop 
    | whileloop
    ;

inp
    : IDENTIFIER "=" INPUT LEFT_BKT literal RIGHT_BKT {printf("Input");}
    | IDENTIFIER "=" RAW_INPUT LEFT_BKT literal RIGHT_BKT {printf("Raw Input");}

print
    : PRINT "\"" literal "\""
    | PRINT expression
    | expression
    ;

expression
    : "+" "*" number "+" "*" number {printf("Expression");}
    | bktexpression {printf("Expression");}
    | "+" "*" number "+" "*" number expression {printf("Expression");}

bktexpression
    : expression LEFT_BKT expression RIGHT_BKT expression
    ;

forloop
    : FOR IDENTIFIER IN "xrange" LEFT_BKT number","number","number RIGHT_BKT ":" statement {printf("For loop");}

whileloop
    : WHILE IDENTIFIER comparison IDENTIFIER statement {printf("While loop");}
    | WHILE IDENTIFIER comparison number statement {printf("While loop");}

if
    : IF IDENTIFIER comparison IDENTIFIER ":" statement {printf("If condition");}
    | IF number comparison number ":" statement {printf("If condition");}
    | IF IDENTIFIER comparison number ":" statement {printf("If condition");}
    | IF number comparison IDENTIFIER ":" statement {printf("If condition");}

else
    : if ELSE ":" statement {printf("Else");}

elif
    : if ELIF IDENTIFIER comparison IDENTIFIER ":" statement {printf("Elif condition");}
    | if ELIF number comparison number ":" statement {printf("Elif condition");}
    | if ELIF IDENTIFIER comparison number ":" statement {printf("Elif condition");}
    | if ELIF number comparison IDENTIFIER ":" statement {printf("Elif condition");}

identifier
    : IDENTIFIER {printf("Identifier");}

comparison
    : RELATIONOPR {printf("Comparison");}

initialization
    : string {printf("Initialization");}

string
    : STRING "=" "\""STRING"\"" {printf("string");}

literal
    : STRING INTEGER {printf("Literal");}
    | STRING "." STRING {printf("Literal");}
    | "_"STRING"_" {printf("Literal");}

number
    : INTEGER {$$ = printf("Number");}

class
    : CLASSDEC literal "():" initialization
    | CLASSDEC literal "():" initialization def;

%%

main()
{

    return (yyparse());
}

yyerror (s) char *s;
{
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

yywrap()
{
    return(1);
}
```

I'm getting these warnings from yacc about useless rules in my grammar:

```
grammarwoindentation.y: warning: 18 nonterminals useless in grammar [-Wother]
grammarwoindentation.y: warning: 41 rules useless in grammar [-Wother]
grammarwoindentation.y:18.131-139: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: statement [-Wother]
 stmt : IMPORT STRING stmt {printf("Parsed import.\n");} | number | def {printf("def");} | initialization stmt {printf("init");} | statement {printf("somestmt");}
                                                                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:21.1-3: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: int [-Wother]
 int : literal "=" number {printf("Integer");}
 ^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:22.1-6: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: assign [-Wother]
 assign : literal "=" literal {printf("Assign");}
 ^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:20.124-132: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: condition [-Wother]
 statement: initialization statement {printf("Statement"); }| print statement {printf("Statement"); } |  inp statement|loop|condition;
                                                                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:20.119-122: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: loop [-Wother]
 statement: initialization statement {printf("Statement"); }| print statement {printf("Statement"); } |  inp statement|loop|condition;
                                                                                                                       ^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:20.105-107: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: inp [-Wother]
 statement: initialization statement {printf("Statement"); }| print statement {printf("Statement"); } |  inp statement|loop|condition;
                                                                                                         ^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:20.62-66: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: print [-Wother]
 statement: initialization statement {printf("Statement"); }| print statement {printf("Statement"); } |  inp statement|loop|condition;
                                                              ^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:26.41-50: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: expression [-Wother]
 print : PRINT "\"" literal "\"" | PRINT expression | expression;
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:28.70-82: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: bktexpression [-Wother]
 expression : "+" "*" number "+" "*" number {printf("Expression");} | bktexpression {printf("Expression");}
                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:24.6-12: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: forloop [-Wother]
 loop:forloop|whileloop;
      ^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:24.14-22: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: whileloop [-Wother]
 loop:forloop|whileloop;
              ^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:23.11-12: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: if [-Wother]
 condition:if|else|elif;
           ^^
grammarwoindentation.y:23.14-17: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: else [-Wother]
 condition:if|else|elif;
              ^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:23.19-22: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: elif [-Wother]
 condition:if|else|elif;
                   ^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:47.1-10: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: identifier [-Wother]
 identifier : IDENTIFIER {printf("Identifier");}
 ^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:34.30-39: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: comparison [-Wother]
 whileloop : WHILE IDENTIFIER comparison IDENTIFIER statement {printf("While loop");} | WHILE IDENTIFIER comparison number statement {printf("While loop");}
                              ^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:21.7-13: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: literal [-Wother]
 int : literal "=" number {printf("Integer");}
       ^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:55.1-5: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: class [-Wother]
 class: CLASSDEC literal "():" initialization | CLASSDEC literal "():" initialization def;
 ^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:18.131-161: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 stmt : IMPORT STRING stmt {printf("Parsed import.\n");} | number | def {printf("def");} | initialization stmt {printf("init");} | statement {printf("somestmt");}
                                                                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:20.12-59: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 statement: initialization statement {printf("Statement"); }| print statement {printf("Statement"); } |  inp statement|loop|condition;
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:20.62-100: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 statement: initialization statement {printf("Statement"); }| print statement {printf("Statement"); } |  inp statement|loop|condition;
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:20.105-117: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 statement: initialization statement {printf("Statement"); }| print statement {printf("Statement"); } |  inp statement|loop|condition;
                                                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:20.119-122: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 statement: initialization statement {printf("Statement"); }| print statement {printf("Statement"); } |  inp statement|loop|condition;
                                                                                                                       ^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:20.124-132: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 statement: initialization statement {printf("Statement"); }| print statement {printf("Statement"); } |  inp statement|loop|condition;
                                                                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:21.7-45: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 int : literal "=" number {printf("Integer");}
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:22.10-48: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 assign : literal "=" literal {printf("Assign");}
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:23.11-12: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 condition:if|else|elif;
           ^^
grammarwoindentation.y:23.14-17: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 condition:if|else|elif;
              ^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:23.19-22: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 condition:if|else|elif;
                   ^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:24.6-12: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 loop:forloop|whileloop;
      ^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:24.14-22: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 loop:forloop|whileloop;
              ^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:25.6-71: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 inp: IDENTIFIER "=" INPUT LEFT_BKT literal RIGHT_BKT {printf("Input");} | IDENTIFIER "=" RAW_INPUT LEFT_BKT literal RIGHT_BKT {printf("Raw Input");}
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:25.75-148: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 inp: IDENTIFIER "=" INPUT LEFT_BKT literal RIGHT_BKT {printf("Input");} | IDENTIFIER "=" RAW_INPUT LEFT_BKT literal RIGHT_BKT {printf("Raw Input");}
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:26.9-31: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 print : PRINT "\"" literal "\"" | PRINT expression | expression;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:26.35-50: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 print : PRINT "\"" literal "\"" | PRINT expression | expression;
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:26.54-63: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 print : PRINT "\"" literal "\"" | PRINT expression | expression;
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:28.14-66: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 expression : "+" "*" number "+" "*" number {printf("Expression");} | bktexpression {printf("Expression");}
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:28.70-106: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 expression : "+" "*" number "+" "*" number {printf("Expression");} | bktexpression {printf("Expression");}
                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:29.22-85: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
           | "+" "*" number "+" "*" number expression {printf("Expression");}
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:32.17-67: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 bktexpression : expression LEFT_BKT expression RIGHT_BKT expression;
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:33.11-116: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 forloop : FOR IDENTIFIER IN "xrange" LEFT_BKT number","number","number RIGHT_BKT ":" statement {printf("For loop");}
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:34.13-84: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 whileloop : WHILE IDENTIFIER comparison IDENTIFIER statement {printf("While loop");} | WHILE IDENTIFIER comparison number statement {printf("While loop");}
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:34.88-155: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 whileloop : WHILE IDENTIFIER comparison IDENTIFIER statement {printf("While loop");} | WHILE IDENTIFIER comparison number statement {printf("While loop");}
                                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:36.8-82: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 if :   IF IDENTIFIER comparison IDENTIFIER ":" statement {printf("If condition");}
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:37.11-77: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
    | IF number comparison number ":" statement {printf("If condition");}
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:38.11-81: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
    | IF IDENTIFIER comparison number ":" statement {printf("If condition");}
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:39.11-81: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
    | IF number comparison IDENTIFIER ":" statement {printf("If condition");}
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:41.8-46: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 else : if ELSE ":" statement {printf("Else");}
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:42.8-89: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 elif : if ELIF IDENTIFIER comparison IDENTIFIER ":" statement {printf("Elif condition");}
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:43.12-85: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
     | if ELIF number comparison number ":" statement {printf("Elif condition");}
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:44.12-89: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
     | if ELIF IDENTIFIER comparison number ":" statement {printf("Elif condition");}
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:45.12-89: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
     | if ELIF number comparison IDENTIFIER ":" statement {printf("Elif condition");}
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:47.14-47: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 identifier : IDENTIFIER {printf("Identifier");}
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:49.14-48: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 comparison : RELATIONOPR {printf("Comparison");}
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:53.11-45: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 literal : STRING INTEGER {printf("Literal");} | STRING "." STRING {printf("Literal");} | "_"STRING"_" {printf("Literal");}
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:53.49-86: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 literal : STRING INTEGER {printf("Literal");} | STRING "." STRING {printf("Literal");} | "_"STRING"_" {printf("Literal");}
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:53.90-122: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 literal : STRING INTEGER {printf("Literal");} | STRING "." STRING {printf("Literal");} | "_"STRING"_" {printf("Literal");}
                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:55.8-44: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 class: CLASSDEC literal "():" initialization | CLASSDEC literal "():" initialization def;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammarwoindentation.y:55.48-88: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 class: CLASSDEC literal "():" initialization | CLASSDEC literal "():" initialization def;
```

I'm working on making a basic compiler for Python. Any solutions or problems anyone can identify here?

Comment: You're missing a large number of trailing semicolons in your rules.

Comment: can you mention a few places in the code as an example if you don't mind?

Comment: semicolons to end rules are optional in yacc, so this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: It would be a lot quicker to mention the few places where you've provided them. I've reformatted your rules in the way I've always used so you can see for yourself. I also encourage you to look up a standard expression grammar.

Comment: Useful and meaningful aren't synonyms! The rules that Yacc calls useless express a meaning; just they have no function within the grammar. They do not have a meaning which conveys to the generated parser.

Comment: Have you tried `yacc -v` (or `bison -v`, etc.) to at least get it to tell you what rules aren't being reduced (etc?)

Answer (score 1):

These errors come from rules that can never expand to something that doesn't include themselves.  For example, in your rules for `statement`

```
statement
    : initialization statement {printf("Statement"); }
    | print statement {printf("Statement"); }
    | inp statement
    | loop
    | condition
    ;
```

*EVERY* alternative includes `statement` on the right side, either directly or indirectly (every `loop` or `condition` rule includes `statement`), which results in an infinite recursion (a parser loop that can never terminate), so yacc gives you a warning that the rule can never be reduced.

The usual way to define rules for things that can be repeated but don't require an infinite sequence be would be something like:

```
statement: initialization | print | inp | loop | condition ;

statement_list: statement | statement_list statement ;
```

and then change the `loop` and `condition` rules to contain `statement_list` rather than `statement`.

This way you have a base case for the recursion where `statement` matches a single statement and a recusive rule where `statement_list` matches one or more staements.

Answer (score 1):

At least some of the non-terminals mentioned do not appear in the right-hand side of any productions. `int` for example. They are therefore useless.

Comment: See, I'm even resolving "def" to its terminals but when I write def funct():" it still gives a syntax error (does not parse).